SQL query to create running balance on hand?
In Teradata, I have a query that returns date, initial, sales, and deliveries.
SELECT
 date, initial, sales, deliveries
FROM sample

I would like to create a new column that acts as a running balance on hand, where the calculation is BOH = initial - sales + deliveries. However, the boh calculation should not begin until the first date when initial is non-zero.
Below is ideally what the column boh should return. How would I go about structuring a query for this?
date  initial  sales  deliveries   boh
---------------------------------------
01-01    0       2        4         0       
01-02    0       0        0         0
01-03    3       1        0         2
01-04    0       4        8         6
01-05    0       2        2         6
01-06    0       1        3         8


You could calculate the earliest date and use it to dertermine if a calculation should be performed.
SELECT 
"date", "initial", "sales", 
SUM(CASE WHEN "date" >= (SELECT MIN("date") FROM tmytable WHERE initial > 0) 
  then  ("initial" - sales + deliveries) 
  ELSE 0 END) OVER(ORDER bY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) boh
FROM tmYtable




date
initial
sales
boh




01-01
0
2
0


01-02
0
0
0


01-03
3
1
2


01-04
0
4
6


01-05
0
2
6


01-06
0
1
8




SELECT 6


fiddle

For Teradata, the default aggregation group is ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING so for a cumulative sum you want OVER( ORDER BY "date" ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )

I don't have a Teradata database handy so I ran the following query in PostgreSQL:
select x.*,
  sum(case when mi <> 0 then initial - sales + deliveries else 0 end) 
    over(order by date) as boh
from (
  select t.*, max(initial) over(order by date) as mi
  from t
) x

Result:
 date   initial  sales  deliveries  mi  boh 
 ------ -------- ------ ----------- --- --- 
 01-01  0        2      4           0   0   
 01-02  0        0      0           0   0   
 01-03  3        1      0           3   2   
 01-04  0        4      8           3   6   
 01-05  0        2      2           3   6   
 01-06  0        1      3           3   8   

See running example at db<>fiddle.

For Teradata, window specification for both SUM and MAX will need ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW to give the indicated results.

According to the Teradata Docs that's the default window frame, so there shouldn't be a need to declare it.

@TheImpaler - I think you are reading the docs wrong. For Teradata, the default is ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING.   Having said that, I always specify my windows, because Teradata is different from the ANSI here.

@Andrew I stand corrected.
